# No data showing in tableselect

Tags: forms

This is a very weird one...

I am building a table using

```
'#type' => 'tableselect'
```

I have

```
$header = array('date', 'name', 'email', 'location', 'time');
```

and

```
$options[$result2[$i]['id']] = array(
    'date' => gmdate("d / m / Y", $result2[$i]['timestamp']),
    'name' => $result2[$i]['name'],             
    'email' => $result2[$i]['email'],
    'location' => $str_location,
    'time' => $str_time,
);
```

then I am building the table like this...

```
    $form['table_' . $n] = array(
        '#type' => 'tableselect',
        '#header' => $header,
        '#options' => $options,
        '#prefix' => '<div class="course_requests"><h1>' . $record1->name . '</h1>',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );
```

The problem is this: The rows are showing.... *but with no data in them*!

I can output the `$options` array and it contains the data I want to see in the table.
I have cleared the cache as mentioned [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/125527/tableselect-showing-empty-message-instead-of-options)

Any clues as to why there are the correct rows with the correct columns but with no data?

Answer (score 0):

Ahhhh!

Just as I posted this I discovered that my $header was malformed!!

```
$header = array('date', 'name', 'email', 'location', 'time');
```

should have been

```
$header = array('date' => 'Date', 'name' => 'Name', 'email' => 'Email', 'location' => 'Location', 'time' => 'Time');
```

Phew!